# Minimizing a window suspends desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, suspend

When I try minimize a window, I can't do any thing until I switch to another desktop (using keyboard shortcut).

I use sidekick effect, but it's also happens when I don't have any effect. What is strange is, that this issue appears only for the last window on a desktop. If I have three windows, I can minimize the first two without problems, but last one always causes suspending.

Log from `glxinfo`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 220/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 331.38
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 331.38
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Open *Ubuntu Tweak*, install it if you haven't done so yet
2. Go to *Tweaks*
3. Then *Desktop Icons*
4. Then check *On* in *Show Desktop Icons*